# Swap two windows when there are three

Tags: vim

I have the following window arrangement in Vim:

```
┌─────┬─────┐
│     │  2  │
│  1  ├─────┤
│     │  3  │
└─────┴─────┘
```

I want to swap windows 2 and 3. Now window 2 is active. <kbd>CTRL-w</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> wouldn't work, because it will then bring window 2 to the bottom and window 1 and 3 on the top as two vertically split windows.

After that, I tried to use other <kbd>CTRL-w</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>/<kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>L</kbd> movements, but wasn't able to achieve the final result.

How can one actually do that?

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:h window-moving` (or simply `:h windows` and then browsing down) lists all such stuff.

I believe you want <kbd>CTRL-w</kbd><kbd>CTRL-x</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL-w</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>) (Window eXchange).

Comment: Also Ctrl-w Ctrl-r

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that Matt's answer is what you are looking for. It only allows to swap the window with the next window. This may work for the given example but not for more complex situations.

I use the vim-windowswap plugin which allows to swap any two windows: https://github.com/wesQ3/vim-windowswap

Comment: Ive been using simeji/winresizer for years and it offers this and more.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you very much. Looks fantastic, continuous resize is something i wish for. So I definitely give it a try. But does it really have a simple swap two windows command? I can't see that

Comment: Its called window move mode (not quite a simple swap command)